# What is the proper etiquette for modifying a repo, then publishing it for an unrelated use?

Tags: licensing, github, etiquette

I have cloned [electron-quick-start](https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start), which is licensed as CC0 1.0 (Public Domain). It's purpose is to help new users to learn Electron. I used it as a scaffolding to make a utility app that I'm using for live debugging.  I would like to make this available others to use, but want to make sure I'm doing it in the right way.  The changes I've made don't necessarily contribute to the intent of the original repo, so I don't feel like I should be forking and making a pull request.

Do I just delete the old repo history, rename everything, and put it on Github with a mention of where it came from?  Should I at least preserve the git history?  What should I do in this situation to preserve history and attribution, yet completely rebrand it as a utility app?

Comment: What does the developers of the original project say about your changes.  They may want them anyway :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First rule, do not fork. Forking is only used on GitHub to contribute changes back (which shouldn't be the case for you).

You can, at your preference, decide to clone the repo and keep the history, which won't be a problem if your project becomes big as the original repo only has a short history of 92 commits. Or choose to just take the code and create a brand new history. In that second case, the first commit could be "Import code from github.com/electron/electron-quick-start." or something along these lines.

You do not *have to* do anything else to preserve attribution as it is not required by the license. However putting a link back from your README would be a nice thing to do. More importantly, as remarked by Glenn Randers-Pehrson, by keeping track of where you got the code, it also establishes your own right to use or convey the code to others (i.e, establishes provenance).

Comment: I'll just keep the history, and note it in the readme.  Thank you!